# UDP datagram only showing first character in Java

Tags: java, udp, datagram

I'm trying to make an `Echo` server-client UDP application. The client is supposed to send over 20 numbers and the server will just send them back. However, from what I have, it shows only the `first character` from the `String` is being sent. I've asked my professor for help but he couldn't figure it out either. Some help would be nice. Thank you!

Client.java:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;

public class client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DatagramSocket socket;
        try {
            socket = new DatagramSocket();
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
            byte[] buf = new byte[256];
            for (Integer i = 1; i < 21; i++) {
                buf = i.toString().getBytes();
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, address, 4445);
                socket.send(packet);
                packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
                socket.receive(packet);
                String received = new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength());
                System.out.println("Server: " + received);
            }
            socket.close();
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Server.java:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;

public class server {
    public static void main(String argsp[]) {
        DatagramSocket socket;
        try {
            socket = new DatagramSocket(4445);
            byte[] buf = new byte[256];
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
            while (true) {
                socket.receive(packet);
                String message = new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength());
                System.out.println("Client: " + message);
                buf = message.getBytes();
                InetAddress address = packet.getAddress();
                int port = packet.getPort();
                packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, address, port);
                socket.send(packet);
            }
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Client output:

```
Server: 1
Server: 2
Server: 3
Server: 4
Server: 5
Server: 6
Server: 7
Server: 8
Server: 9
Server: 1
Server: 1
Server: 1
Server: 1
Server: 1
Server: 1
Server: 1
Server: 1
Server: 1
Server: 1
Server: 2
```

Server output:

```
Client: 1
Client: 2
Client: 3
Client: 4
Client: 5
Client: 6
Client: 7
Client: 8
Client: 9
Client: 1
Client: 1
Client: 1
Client: 1
Client: 1
Client: 1
Client: 1
Client: 1
Client: 1
Client: 1
Client: 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you receive a datagram the `DatagramPacket` shrinks to the length. So, in your server, it shrinks to 1 after the first receive. You need to recreate it inside the receive lopo, or a least reset its length at the top of the loop.

Comment: I did not know that. I thought if I define `buf` and the `DatagramPacket` before I enter the loop, they would stay the same throughout. Thank you for your help!